# Pandas - Duplicate rows while creating a dataframe from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

I have the following code where I talk to a service to get data. The dictionary that is returned from this service looks like below

```
{'karnatakaCount': 44631, 'bangaloreCount': 20870, 'mangaloreCount': 985, 'kodaguCount': 743, 'udupiCount': 556, 'kasargodCount': 673, 'mangaloreVaccinations': 354095, 'karnatakaVaccinations': 9892349, 'keralaVaccinations': 7508437, 'mangaloreDeath': 4, 'indiaDailyConfirmed': 382602}
```

I want to store these values in a CSV file for which I had created a script using Pandas and  then saving it to a CSV file. While creating the file, I get multiple duplicate values which looks as follows

[image: enter code here]

The code looks like below

```
import pandas as pd
from getData import getData
from datetime import datetime

data = getData()
print(data)
dateToday=str(datetime.now().day)+","+str(datetime.now().strftime('%B'))+""+str(datetime.now().year)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=list(data.keys()))
df['Date'] = dateToday
# df.drop_duplicates(subset='Date', inplace=True)
df.to_csv('data1.csv',index=False)
```

To remove the duplicates, I have added the following code.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Date', inplace=True)
```

How do I avoid this line and why is my data repeating in the DataFrame?

Comment: Are there duplicate rows before you add the date column?  If so, what is going on in the getData() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=list(data.keys()))`.

[pandas.DataFrame()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) can accepts a list of dictionary or a dictionary whose value is list-like objects.

- a list of dictionary

```py
[{'karnatakaCount': 44631, 'bangaloreCount': 20870}, {'karnatakaCount': 44631, 'bangaloreCount': 20870}]
```

- a dictionary whose value is list-like objects

```py
{'karnatakaCount': [44631], 'bangaloreCount': [20870]}
```

However, your data is a dictionary whose value only contains constants.

```py
{'karnatakaCount': 44631, 'bangaloreCount': 20870}
```

Pandas fails to determine how many rows to create. If you do `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` in your example, pandas will give you an error

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

The usage of `index` is to determine how many times you want to repeat the data. In your example, you choose to repeat it `list(data.keys())` times. That's why you got so many duplicated rows.

You can use `df = pd.DataFrame([data])` to create one row dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Just try the [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

And then create a new column with the keys and assgin it as index.

```
df.set_index('column_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `from_dict` method after reformatting your data as such :

```
data["Date"] = str(datetime.now().day)+","+str(datetime.now().strftime('%B'))+""+str(datetime.now().year)
data = {k:[v] for k,v in data.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```